# Is it okay to have $compile inside the link part of a directive?

Tags: angularjs

I am using AngularJS v1.4.1 and I have the following directive. It was I thought working but now for some reason when my page loads the directive gets called twice. I checked everything I could but I cannot see anything different from before to now except the directive no longer works. Specifically what happens is it appears to be getting called twice.

```
app.directive('pagedownAdmin', ['$compile','$timeout', function ($compile, $timeout) {
    var nextId = 0;
    var converter = Markdown.getSanitizingConverter();
    converter.hooks.chain("preBlockGamut", function (text, rbg) {
        return text.replace(/^ {0,3}""" *\n((?:.*?\n)+?) {0,3}""" *$/gm, function (whole, inner) {
            return "<blockquote>" + rbg(inner) + "</blockquote>\n";
        });
    });

    return {
        require: 'ngModel',
        replace: true,
        scope: {
            modal: '=modal'
        },
        template: '<div class="pagedown-bootstrap-editor"></div>',
        link: function (scope, iElement, attrs: any, ngModel) {

            var editorUniqueId;

            if (attrs.id == null) {
                editorUniqueId = nextId++;
            } else {
                editorUniqueId = attrs.id;
            }

            scope.showPagedownButtons = function () {
                document.getElementById("wmd-button-bar-" + editorUniqueId).style.display = 'block';
            };

            var newElement = $compile(
                '<div>' +
                '<div class="wmd-panel">' +


                '<div data-ng-hide="modal.wmdPreview == true" id="wmd-button-bar-' + editorUniqueId + '" style="display:none;"></div>' +

                '<textarea ng-click="showPagedownButtons()" data-ng-hide="modal.wmdPreview == true" class="wmd-input" id="wmd-input-' + editorUniqueId + '">' +
                '</textarea>' +

                '</div>' +

                '<div data-ng-show="modal.wmdPreview == true" id="wmd-preview-' + editorUniqueId + '" class="pagedownPreview wmd-panel wmd-preview"></div>' +

                '</div>')(scope);

            // iElement.html(newElement);
            iElement.append(newElement);

            var hide = function () {
                document.getElementById("wmd-button-bar-" + editorUniqueId).style.display = 'none';
            }

            var editor = new Markdown.Editor(converter, "-" + editorUniqueId, {
                handler: hide
            });

            // var $wmdInput = iElement.find('#wmd-input-' + editorUniqueId);
            var $wmdInput = angular.element(document.getElementById("wmd-input-" + editorUniqueId));



            var init = false;

            editor.hooks.chain("onPreviewRefresh", function () {
                var val = $wmdInput.val();
                if (init && val !== ngModel.$modelValue) {
                    $timeout(function () {
                        scope.$apply(function () {
                            ngModel.$setViewValue(val);
                            ngModel.$render();
                        });
                    });
                }
            });

            ngModel.$formatters.push(function (value) {
                init = true;
                $wmdInput.val(value);
                editor.refreshPreview();
                return value;
            });

            editor.run();
        }
    }
}]);
```

Here is the code that calls the directive:

```
 <textarea data-pagedown-admin
                          data-modal="cos"
                          id="contentText"
                          name="contentText"
                          ng-minlength="5"
                          ng-model="cos.content.text"
                          ng-required="true"></textarea>
```

When I debug the directive by putting a breakpoint on "var editorUniqueId" then I see it goes there twice.

Does anyone have any ideas what might be happening?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have done this in the past without issue:

```
var newElement = '<div>' +
    // ... more HTML ...
'</div>';

iElement.append( $compile(newElement)(scope) );
```